# how to access wsl localhost in browser when connecting via SSH?

Tags: ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using ssh and vscode to remote development with angular. My server is a Windows Machine where WSL is running, and I am connecting to the WSL. In the WSL server I am calling `ng serve` and I get the regular message `** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **`

The problem is, I have no idea how to access that in browser, I tried `MY_SERVER_IP:4200` but it does not work.

Do I have to activate something in WSL for it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I cannot fully imagine your infrastructure setup (where does your SSH connection run between?) I guess that you simply need to enhance the SSH connection by a port forwarding for tcp/4200 from the server to your local machine.
Depending on your SSH client, the tunnel is established..

- Linux ssh command: something like -L4200:127.0.0.1:4200
- Putty: right click the window header, go to connection/tunnels and enter it (don't forget to click on Apply before Close)